# Extract data from one table to anoher

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a main database. I do extraction some data to DataTable and then need to update private database with this data avoiding doubling. When I use Update command, data doubling in a private database, in case of Fill nothing happens at all.

Here the code:

```
Dim Table As New DataTable
cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Main.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=123")
cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn}
cn.Open()
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Catalogue"
DA = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
DA.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False
DA.Fill(Table)
DA.Dispose()
cn.Close()
'--------------
cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=private.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=123"
cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn}
cn.Open()
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Catalogue"
DA = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
MyBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(DA)
DA.Fill(Table) 'ADD NO DATA
DA.Update(Table) 'DOUBLING DATA
DA.Dispose()
cn.Close()
```

As you understand, when I talk about doubling data, it's mean I have already some data in a private database and they can be the same as data in main database.

Problem visualization:

Begining

```
Main database, table 1 data
 1
 2
 3

Private database, table 1 data
 1
 2
```

Ending

```
What I need:
 Private database, table 1 data
 1
 2
 3

What I get:
 Private database, table 1 data
 1
 2
 1
 2
 3
```

Comment: Why not backup `main` db, then restore other one?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are just wanting to keep the duplicates out of the database? What database are you using? Access? What year?

Answer (score 0):

Sad here is no replies notification. I solved this problem by recommendation from other forum. It's needed to be read from main database, then from the client and at the end merged. Then duplicated records will be removed.